# gzip_css will not render on my server

Tags: php, apache2, gzip, lamp, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working with a repo that uses grunt to gzip scripts and stylesheets. The stylesheets will not render in my browser and I think it may have something to do with the apache2 configuration on my ubuntu 14.04 OS.

When I open up the source code and click on the style.gz.css file I notice that the browser does not render the styles. Instead I see

```
‹´(Tstyle.css�í½û›·‘(úóÎ_ÑGúôYòRÍæ{t’7±ÏúÄëì½7ÚÏñÕ4ÙÍ™ŽH‚é&53Þ{ÿ÷ _xTègFYO"kÔ(�U…ªB¡�~—ì$=z§tûúöx<\½}»!ûc6¼!äf‡‡$®Éîí:Ëþyî’íÃo¾äjìû—“üOr·Éúr^þöæÝÅÛ/¿¼ð¾ô~w×Ã›øŸþ¯~$7ññ6Nù÷ðt¼%é?ýé.Þ{?…ûðæÖ{ëý1‰SB¿Äñ>ÜSÀ·´!ï7½ý\xž÷=IwÉ_âaFIò²øxLö7+ê¯£sÎ‚o÷ëí)Š3oß„ëo•’»,N½ìtà|ÿöëÙÛ9d°?ÄGïH¼M¸Íb/ÙxääÝ…{þ1JÉ¡ª´!)«è…ûˆþ=/9õ/aŸÑãÅ›ð´e(P¼r`èeá>Pº’ÍCïßÓøSLa’?ýàãû£—Q¦{aô·SvôÂÍ‘ò€¤    …..................
```

The files will parse on MAMP, XAMPP but not LAMP. Has anyone had this issue and how did you solve it?

Here is an example of how gruntfile.js i set up.

```
exec: {
        gzip_js: {
            command: 'gzip -9 js/script.min.js',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        },
        gzip_js_rename: {
            command: 'mv js/script.min.js.gz js/script.<%= asset_revision %>.min.gz.js',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        },
        gzip_css: {
            command: 'gzip -9 css/style.css',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        },
        gzip_css_rename: {
            command: 'mv css/style.css.gz css/style.<%= asset_revision %>.gz.css',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        },
        gzip_standalone_js: {
            command: 'gzip -9 js/gzip/modernizr-detectizr.min.js',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        },
        gzip_standalone_js2: {
            command: 'gzip -9 js/gzip/respond.min.js',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        },
        gzip_standalone_js3: {
            command: 'gzip -9 js/gzip/select-ie8.min.js',
            stdout: false,
            stderr: false
        }
    },
```

I do not have much experience editing the php.ini files but one edit I did make under recommendation was to uncomment the below lines.

```
zlib.output_compression = 4096                                             
                                                                       │zlib.output_compression_level = 6                                          
                                                                       │zlib.output_handler = ob_gzhandler
```

Other than this edit I have not tried to make to many edits to the php.ini file.

So if you have had a similar problem and were able to solve the issue I would love to hear from you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After going through the .htaccess file of the repo I realised some modules were not enabled in my apache2 server.

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

and then restart the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

problem solved.

Hope this helps anyone else having similar issues.